# Why is this question considered "off-topic"?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, specific-question

Earlier today I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27493303/274579) in SO. Some users thought it was off-topic.

Help center definition for off-topicness is:

> - "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")
>     must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the
>     shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.
>     Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other
>     readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable
>     example."

Honestly, I can't see how the question does not answer to these requirements:

First, it is a programming question, not related to a specific tool. Then,

> must include the desired behavior

I mentioned what I expect the outcome to be (set `*x`).

> a specific problem or error

I mentioned what I see (`x = NULL`)

> the shortest code necessary to reproduce it

I added a compilable and executable code snippet, which I tested on my IDE, that can't really get shorter than that.

So, can someone explain why this question would be considered off-topic?

Comment: I'm not a C / C++ expert by any means, but I think one of the reasons is that your minimal example doesn't make sense or stems from a significant misunderstanding of constructors. Think about what happens when you call the constructor `A(y)` outside of the class - now, why should anything different happen when you call `A(y)` from within a method? That would be very counter-intuitive. The answer by Christophe describes your error. Disregarding that, the requirement "I want to reuse the constructor" doesn't make much sense in the first place - the pragmatic answer is "just use a normal method".

Comment: @l4mpi - thanks, but I don't think you explained why it is off-topic, or did I miss something?

Comment: Well, as I said the minimal example and the requirement don't make much sense; thus the question feels like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Furthermore, it's not that useful in its current state; it basically boils down to "I thought this would work but it doesn't, why?" rather than focussing on an actual (nontrivial) problem.

Comment: @l4mpi - I guess we are in a disagreement here. I don't think the question falls under the XY category. I also do not think that "it doesn't make sense", and the few attempted solutions show that at least a couple more participants share my opinion.

Comment: But anyway, I am not trying to *defend* my question, but rather to understand the motivation and logic of those who down-voted it as off-topic.

Comment: The problem is that C++ devs are in a constant state of aggravation caused by being a C++ dev.  If you venture into their tag and post a question that is overtly noobish or is trivial or obviously wrong or easily answered with a little research they will come down on you like a ton of bricks.  I'd suggest asking C++ questions *as a last resort*, or alternatively, drop C++ and start using C#.  Better language and platform, friendlier folks, no pointer arithmetic.

Comment: "Down vote" and "vote to close" are not the same thing.

Comment: @Will - LOL. So true. I tried to be very gentle in *my* replies (nevertheless, if you look at the edit history of this question you'll see how a minor sarcasm is also intolerable here) ... but this situation dates back to comp.lang.c++ days...

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce - I stand corrected. It should have been "vote to close".

Comment: I have no clue about C++. But all the technical discussion within that question, i.m.h.o. show clearly that it's not off-topic and not even trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't downvote it or vote to close it, but I can see why others did:

> I mentioned what I expect the outcome to be (set *x).

How do you expect that to be observed? Your program doesn't seem to have any visible side effects. Do you expect everyone looking at your question to step through in a debugger?

> I mentioned what I see (x = NULL)

How do you see that? Why can't you make the code demonstrate that?

Wouldn't adding a single `printf` (or equivalent) make it easier to verify that?

If you spend one minute making the program display the problem then you save 10 or more people all spending one minute doing exactly the same thing (or more likely, they don't bother, vote to close and move on to a question that doesn't require them to spend a minute adding output to the code).

> I added a compilable and executable code snippet, which I tested on my IDE, that can't really get shorter than that.

Your code snippet is split in two with English text in the middle, it can't be simply cut&pasted into a C++ file.

It doesn't have any output, so it's not clear whether or not it behaves as you expect or as you claim it does.

Other than that the snippet is OK.

**Edit:** Here is a MCVE that prints out what is happening: http://ideone.com/MBCWBU

Note that this *doesn't even compile* using GCC and the compiler error might give you a clue about what the code does.

Comment: Thanks. You are right that adding diagnostics inline would improve understanding the problem, and I take your advice for saving future time spent by other users - I definitely should be more considerate. But these are merely stylistic suggestions, so how is this "off-topic"??

Comment: "Your code snippet is split in two with English text in the middle" - seriously, Jonathan?

Comment: BTW, MSVC 2013 did not give a message in the line of "shadowing a parameter (or any message at all). I am not sure what this message means, anyway...

Comment: OK, re-read that message, I see what it means now (merely, declaring a local variable `y` inside the method, which overrides the argument `y`).

Comment: Yes, seriously. It is not a "complete" example if it's in two pieces! But as I said, "other than that the snippet is OK". It is "off-topic" because that is the StackOverflow category that applies to code that is missing "the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself." Your example code only reproduced the problem for people willing to step through it in a debugger.

Comment: OK, at last some *positive* approach here! I can live with this reasoning (if hard pressed), so I guess we can wrap up the discussion. Thanks for your efforts here and in the SO thread.